# How do I download and unzip a program in C #

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making the launcher for the game server. How can I get the game to download and unzip it. I have a zip file I prepared, I want it to download and install "C: \ Program Files" automatically.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;

namespace WindowsFormsApp3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        WebClient web = new WebClient();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void DosyaIndirmeTamamlandiUyarisi(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Download Completed");
        }

        private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DosyaIndirmeTamamlandiUyarisi);

            Uri DosyaAdresi = new Uri(textBox1.Text);
            web.DownloadFileAsync(DosyaAdresi, textBox1.Text.Length.ToString()+".zip");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And which part are you struggling with? It looks like you managed to download the file. See [How to: Compress and extract files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files) for the second task. Also, note that in order to access the `%ProgramFiles%` folder, you're going to need to elevate your process (AKA, run as administrator).

Comment: I tried it like this but it doesn't unzip. pastecode.io/s/1hija2BtUu

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files

Unzip files.
Add async and await to your code.

Change to your own settings.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private WebClient _webClient;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _webClient = new WebClient();
        }

        private async void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Uri DosyaAdresi = new Uri(@"https://zaycev.net/download/packie/ae4cce5699f15a877ff42559b5a2555d/9443");
            var fileName = "download";
            await _webClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(DosyaAdresi, fileName + ".zip");
            DirectoryInfo unZipDir = new DirectoryInfo("unzip");
            if (!unZipDir.Exists)
            {
                unZipDir.Create();
            }
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName + ".zip", unZipDir.FullName);
        }
```

Comment: I tried it like this but it doesn't unzip. https://pastecode.io/s/1hija2BtUu

Comment: @YavuzAdem Unzip unzips to a folder. I updated the answer

Comment: @ DirectoryInfo unZipDir = new DirectoryInfo("unzip"); Instead of unzip, specify your directory.